# How to auto-generate an alphabetical set of quicklinks for a <dl> glossary?

Tags: php, jquery, html, navigation, glossary

I have a relatively large glossary of terms on my webpage which are organized as a description list `<dl>`.

For the sake of a minimum working example, let's suppose looks something like the following (except it would have 50-100 entries):

```
<dl class="glossary">

    <dt>Bobcat</dt>
    <dd>A medium-sized, furry mammal that can eat children.</dd>

    <dt>Cat</dt>
    <dd>A small, furry mammal that meows.</dd>

    <dt>Dog</dt>
    <dd>A small, furry mammal that barks.</dd>

    <dt>Fish</dt>
    <dd>A scaly aquatic animal that swims in water.</dd>

</dl>
```

Let's assume that all terms are correctly ordered alphabetically within the `<dl>` region via the `<dt>` tag.

**I would like to automatically generate a sequence of ABC hyperlinks at the top of the screen ("A", "B", "C", ..., "Z") which jump to the first entry beginning with that letter. Bonus points if there's a way to include all letters, but style letters differently if there *are* vs. if there *aren't* glossary entries corresponding to that letter.**

What I'm going for should look *very roughly* like the following website, where alphabetical quicklinks near the top of each page point the user to those places in the glossary: http://www.g2conline.org/g2c/glossary/a/. A key difference is that I want the quicklinks to point to anchors on the same page, rather than dividing the glossary into separate pages for each letter of the alphabet, as that website does.

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7uo0q40/2/) of what the result should look and behave like. You may notice that I included CSS and some classes to make certain links look different, according to my "bonus" requirement, above. I also added some extra HTML to produce the links.

I'd love to have something like this happen automatically/dynamically -- perhaps via a JQuery script? I would like to keep this as lightweight as possible and avoid using programming languages other than HTML, PHP or Javascript/JQuery.

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't look as if it would be rocket science to have the [PHP?] examine the words and churn out an ID tag at the right point...

Comment: it sounds like you know what you're doing. which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Kkinsey: Totally -- and thanks. ! I'm just learning all this, however. I'd rather not reinvent the wheel and do all the code myself if somebody has already done a good job of it. (I also don't know PHP well enough to do that...yet!)

Comment: stackoverflow is not a site where people write code for you. post your code, and mention the specific parts you're having trouble with.

Comment: Is the page *generated* by PHP?

Comment: @sgroves: I know how to do the HTML side of things -- I could easily hard-code everything. I'd love to go from the code I posted above to something like the JSFiddle code I linked to -- dynamically if possible. I don't know how to do this automatically/dynamically. I'd like to avoid hard-coding everything because I'm working on it a lot, so the content is changing frequently, and I would like to not have to keep moving the alphabetical anchors when I add new glossary entries.

Comment: @Kkinsey: No. I write all the content myself. I do include a few php pages for a consistent header, navbar, and footer across several other pages on my site.

Comment: @jvriesem sounds like a plan. first, learn the basics of javascript. then tackle this problem. feel free to ask questions on SO as you go.

Comment: @sgroves: Agreed, learning Javascript or PHP would help me solve this myself. I also fully agree StackOverflow isn't meant for people write code for others. I honestly am not sure how big of a problem this will be, or how much code or even what kind of code it will require. What I'm looking for is whether anyone knows if this has been done before, and if so, whether I could just include a script in my code to do it for me. If somebody solved this in 4-10 lines, I'd be very grateful, but it's not what I'm expecting. Plus, it's an interesting problem that doesn't have an easy-to-find solution!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, but it took a while. I ended up learning Javascript/JQuery in the process!

**Here's a JSFiddle of what I wrote:**  http://jsfiddle.net/w7uo0q40/10/ 
I added a few more glossary terms so that you can see the hyperlinks actually do something when you click on them. The letter-links at the top that have entries point to the first entry with that letter, whereas the letters at the top which do not have entries look different and do not link to anything.

Here's the accompanying code (copied from the JSFiddle):

**Javascript/JQuery**

```
var terms = $("dl.glossary dt").sort();

var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    var nextChar = letters.charAt(i);

    // Need to find first of each letter
    var foundOne = -999;
    for (var j = 0; j < terms.length; j++) {
        var termj = terms[j].innerText;
        var termJJ = termj.toUpperCase();
        if (termJJ.charAt(0) == nextChar) {
            foundOne = j;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Create links and anchors based on whether something was found
    if (foundOne == -999) {

        // Create a new letterLink (with class "entriesAbsent")
        newLetterLink = "<span class=\"letterLinkSpan\"><a class=\"letterLink entriesAbsent\">" + nextChar + "</a></span>";

    } else {

        // Create a new letterLink (with class "entriesPresent")
        newLetterLink = "<span class=\"letterLinkSpan\"><a class=\"letterLink entriesPresent\" href=\"#" + nextChar + "\">" + nextChar + "</a></span>";

        // Create an anchor for the letterLink BEFORE the first glossary term starting with that letter
        $("<a class=\"letterAnchor\" name=\"" + nextChar + "\">").insertBefore(terms[foundOne]);

    }

    // Either way, add the letterLink to the list of letterLinks
    $("div#quicklinks").append(newLetterLink);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h2>Glossary:</h2>

<h3>Links:</h3> 
<div id="quicklinks"></div>

<h3>Entries:</h3> 
<dl class="glossary"> <a name="Bobcat">
    <dt>Bobcat</dt>
        <dd>A medium-sized, furry mammal that can eat children.</dd>
    <a name="Cat">
    <dt>Cat</dt>
        <dd>A small, furry mammal that meows.</dd>
    <a name="Dog">
    <dt>Dog</dt>
        <dd>A small, furry mammal that barks.</dd>
    <a name="Fish">
    <dt>Fish</dt>
        <dd>A scaly aquatic animal that swims in water.</dd>
    <a name="Flamingo">
    <dt>Flamingo</dt>
        <dd>A pink bird.</dd>
    <a name="Gnat">
    <dt>Gnat</dt>
        <dd>A small flying insect.</dd>
    <a name="Llama">
    <dt>Llama</dt>
        <dd>A shaggy-haired beast of burden with a long neck.</dd>
    <a name="Mouse">
    <dt>Mouse</dt>
        <dd>A tiny mammal.</dd>
    <a name="Quail">
    <dt>Quail</dt>
        <dd>A small bird.</dd>
    <a name="Rhino">
    <dt>Rhino</dt>
        <dd>A scaly mammal.</dd>
    <a name="Swan">
    <dt>Swan</dt>
        <dd>A white bird.</dd>
    <a name="Toucan">
    <dt>Toucan</dt>
        <dd>A colorful bird.</dd>
    <a name="Whale">
    <dt>Whale</dt>
        <dd>A huge aquatic mammal.</dd>
    <a name="Yak">
    <dt>Yak</dt>
        <dd>A shaggy-haired beast of burden.</dd>
    <a name="Zebra">
    <dt>Zebra</dt>
        <dd>Sort of a horse with white/black stripes.</dd>

</dl>
```

**CSS**

```
span.letterLinkSpan {
    display: inline-block;
}
span.letterLinkSpan>a.letterLink {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.1em;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.2em;
    font-size: medium;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #BBCCFF;
}

span.letterLinkSpan>a.letterLink.entriesPresent {
    font-weight: bold;
}
span.letterLinkSpan>a.letterLink.entriesAbsent {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #FFEEEE;
}
span.letterLinkSpan>a.letterLink:hover {
    background-color: #DDDDFF;
}
```

It's not particularly elegant code, but hopefully this will help somebody. Cheers!